# Internet bandwidth mysteriously drops under Linux, but is fine under Windows

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, bandwidth

I can't seem to download files from the internet on my laptop with Mint/Ubuntu, due to strange bandwidth fluctuations.

I'm able to browse the web with Firefox with no problems, `apt-get update` and `dist-upgrade` work normally, both my Firefox, Deluge and Transmission have standard settings, I haven't tweaked anything.

Yet every time its the same story: a file starts downloading either via direct download or torrent; initial speed is around 1MB/s and several MBs are downloaded. Then the speed decreases gradually until it reaches 0. After some interval (5-20min) it again rises to around 800MB/s, downloads 1-2 MBs and then decreases to 0.

After a while, in case of direct download almost nothing is downloaded and often I get an error window that say could not download the file. The same files are downloaded within 5-10min via my desktop with win7.

Any ideas as to what may be the cause?

Comment: Does `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` shed any light on what's going on?

Comment: Im a newbie to linux, so You would have to tell me what to look for in `dmesg` and `syslog`. To me its a huge bunch of text and I dont know even where to start. Forgot to mention, firewall is turned off

Comment: You'll need to post the contents of these 2 to http://pastebin.com so I can look at it then. We'll be here for 2 weeks if I have to walk you through them 8-). Post the links here when you've got them there.

Comment: Thanks slm for Your help and interest. By accident I found the solution - my broadcom BCM4313 drivers were listed in devices and drivers, but were not selected. After turning them on everything works fine! I am a new user and apparently my reputation prevents me from answering my own questions, so maybe You could answer it for me. So `dmesg` and `syslog` are not beginner-friendly topics? :)

Comment: `dmesg` and `syslog` are readable, but require some time to gain understanding about. They are attainable to a beginner but will require an hour or 2 to get. If you wait 8 hours you can provide your own answer. I'd encourage you to do this. http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved.

What I neglected to do, was to check under `settings > devices and drivers` and see if my drivers for Broadcom BRC4313 are selected or not. Which they weren't.
After turning on the driver, bandwith returned to normal